# R: annotate within an equation

Tags: r

Is it possible to annotate within an equation in R?  For example:

```
100 /* item 1 */ + 200 /* item 2 */
```

giving an answer of 300.

I think `/*  */` is C code.  Although, I am not certain `100 /* item 1 */ + 200 /* item 2 */` will run in C.

If I use `100 # item 1 # + 200 # item 2 #` in R I get an answer of 100 because everything after the first `#` is ignored, as I expected.

I suppose I could use:

```
#  item 1     item 2
   100    +    200
```

I was just thinking that when equations become really long and complex taking up several lines it might be nice to annotate within an equation.

The following works and returns 300:

```
(100 +  # item 1
 200  ) # item 2
```

That requires a new line after every annotation and is the closest that I can come to my initial example above containing only one line.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You can get rid of the () in the last example, which is the usual way to comment items in R. I use is extensively to comment function parameters.

Comment: It's far better, IMHO, to break up complicated (not necessarily "complex", which means x+iy :-) ) equations into several steps.  The alternative is to provide several comment lines defining each term in the equation, as is done in technical papers and books.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible. As noted in the [Comments section of the R language manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Comments), the only comment character is #. Everything from the # to the end of the line is ignored (unless the # is quoted in a string).